# How do I remove a taxonomy from Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I'm creating different custom post types and taxonomies and I want to remove the 'Post Tags' taxonomy from the default 'Posts' post type. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

I suggest you don't mess with the actual global. Its safer to simply deregister the taxonomy from the post type: register_taxonomy is used for both creation and modification.

```
function ev_unregister_taxonomy(){
    register_taxonomy('post_tag', array());
}
add_action('init', 'ev_unregister_taxonomy');
```

To remove the sidebar menu entry:

```
// Remove menu
function remove_menus(){
    remove_menu_page('edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag'); // Post tags
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Comment: Worked for me! Seems like the most localized impact, as well.

Comment: This works, but the link in the sidebar is still there!

Comment: Here is how to remove the sidebar menu entry:

`function remove_menus(){
        remove_menu_page('edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag'); // Post tags
}


add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );`

Comment: This was the simplest solution, also, the menu item was removed for me without the second script.

Comment: One small bug I've found here: the taxonomy will still be included in the show options page when you edit your menus. To fix this, just pass in an additional args array: `register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', array(), array('show_in_nav_menus' => false) );`

Comment: This helped me! I was using `unregister_taxonomy('product_tag')` (for woocommerce) and getting some weird errors in log. Re-registering it as en empty array basically had the same effect and I didn't get any errors  

Comment: @WillHaynes comment obligates the "Remove menus" action entirely. Its now gone everywhere.

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps a more technically correct method would be to use [`unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type/)

```
add_action( 'init', 'unregister_tags' );

function unregister_tags() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'post' );
}
```

Comment: Might not be necessary but you could check if the taxonomy is already associated with the object type before removing it with `if ( is_object_in_taxonomy( 'post', 'post_tag' ) ) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Total unregister and remove (minimal PHP version 5.4!)

```
add_action('init', function(){
        global $wp_taxonomies;
        unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'post' );
        unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'post' );
        if ( taxonomy_exists( 'category'))
            unset( $wp_taxonomies['category']);
        if ( taxonomy_exists( 'post_tag'))
            unset( $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']);
        unregister_taxonomy('category');
        unregister_taxonomy('post_tag');
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Where it says '`taxonomy_to_remove`' is where you'll enter the taxonomy you want to remove. For instance you can replace it with the existing, `post_tag` or `category`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'unregister_taxonomy');
function unregister_taxonomy(){
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $taxonomy = 'taxonomy_to_remove';
    if ( taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy))
        unset( $wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy]);
}
```

Comment: does not answer the question. This just hides it

Answer (score 2):

There is new function to remove taxonomy from WordPress.

`Use unregister_taxonomy( string $taxonomy ) function`

See details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy/

Comment: This can't be used for built-in taxonomies so presumably this can't be used for 'tags'?

Comment: For removing built-in taxonomy like tag we can use this function below:


function mh_unregister_tags_for_posts() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'post' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mh_unregister_tags_for_posts' );

Answer (score 1):

Use it in 'admin_init' hook insetead not 'init'

```
function unregister_taxonomy(){
    register_taxonomy('post_tag', array());
}
add_action('admin_init', 'unregister_taxonomy');
```

Answer (score 1):

`add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items');
function remove_menu_items() {
  remove_submenu_page('edit.php','edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag');
}`