# Wordpress: Disable Tags only for Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I am currently developing a theme for Wordpress 3.8.1. As my theme will not display any tags, so I want do disable them (only from the posts, not from custom post types). But how do I do this? I have tried this, but apparently, it does nothing:

```
register_taxonomy('post_tag', null);
```

To be clear: I do not just want to hide the tags in the template files, but I want to disable them completely, so in the backend, there is no menu item for tags under posts.

Is it even possible? I hope so. Thanks for your help!

### Update

Additionally, I have tried the following, without any effect:

```
register_taxonomy('post_tag', array());
```

and

```
global $wp_taxonomies;
$taxonomy = 'post_tag';
if(taxonomy_exists($taxonomy))
    unset($wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy]);
```

Both remove the tags box while editing a post, but there still is the link in the menu pointing to the list of tags!

Comment: What for? Why disabling whole functionality if you're only going to "not show" them?

Comment: See this link: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93634/remove-post-tag-from-default-post-type-add-custom-taxonomy

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249694/how-do-i-remove-a-taxonomy-from-wordpress

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I want to disable the functionality so the interface is simpler and the user does not have to wonder, why there is an option for tags!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of WordPress 3.7, there is an `unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type` function available for just this sort of thing.

In your case:

```
// Remove tags support from posts
function myprefix_unregister_tags() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'post');
}
add_action('init', 'myprefix_unregister_tags');
```

View the documentation for this function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type/).

Comment: This is the best solution I've found yet. It removes the Tags admin menu item, the Tags column when viewing the list of posts and the Tags metabox when editing a single post.

Answer (score 9):

Paste this code into your functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myprefix_remove_meta_box');
function myprefix_remove_meta_box(){
   remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag','post','normal' );
}
```

`tags` meta box has a class of `tagsdiv-post_tag`, so this will remove the `tags` meta box

OR

```
add_action('init', 'remove_tags');
function remove_tags(){
    register_taxonomy('post_tag', array());
}
```

if you completely want to remove it

Comment: Yes, it removes it, but the link in the left menu sidebar is still there!

Comment: Thank you, but your second version still only removes the box, not the link in the menu!

Comment: Did you try `add_action('init', 'remove_tags');` because for me it removes the ink in the menu which is under posts.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to disable rewrite rules for tags in posts for me was to use the `post_tag_rewrite_rules` filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'post_tag_rewrite_rules', '__return_empty_array' );
```